# Managing set of users

Tags: mysql, redis, persistence, key-value, nosql

We have a website with many users. To manage users who transacted on a given day, we use Redis and stored a list of binary numbers as the values. For instance, if our system had five users, and user 2 and 5 transacted on 2nd January, our key for 2nd January will look like '01001'. This also helps us to determine unique users over a given period and new users using simple bit operations. However, with growing number of users, we are running out of memory to store all these keys.

Is there any alternative database that we can use to store the data in a similar manner? If not, how should we store the data to get similar performance?

Comment: Your design should conform to the volume of data - how many users in total in per day so you have? Possible approaches with Redis could include using Sets or compressing the Bit values

Comment: We have approximately 400K users transacting on a given day. The disk size of the redis snapshot is about 2.5GB, however it takes approximately 54GB in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Redis' nemory usage can be affected by many parameters so I would also try looking in INFO ALL for starters.

With every user represented by a bit, 400K daily visitors should take at least 50KB per value, but due to sparsity in the bitmap index that could be much larger. I'd also suspect that since newer users are more active, the majority of your bitmaps' "active" flags are towards its end, causing it to reach close to its maximal size (i.e. total number of users). So the question you should be trying to answer is how to store these 400K visits efficiently w/o sacrificing the functionality you're using. That actually depends what you're doing with the recorded visits.

For example, if you're only interested in total counts, you could consider using the HyperLogLog data structure to count your transacting users with a low error rate and small memory/resources footprint. On the other hand, if you're trying to track individual users, perhaps keep a per user bitmap mapped to the days since signing up with your site.

Furthermore, there are bitmap compression techniques that you could consider implementing in your application code/Lua scripting/hacking Redis. The best answer would depend on what you're trying to do of course.